# R - Return an object name from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Using a basic function such as this:

```
myname<-function(z){
   nm <-deparse(substitute(z))
   print(nm)
}
```

I'd like the name of the item to be printed (or returned) when iterating through a list e.g.

```
for (csv in list(acsv, bcsv, ccsv)){
myname(csv)
}
```

should print:

```
acsv
bcsv
ccsv
```

(and not csv).

It should be noted that acsv, bcsv, and ccsvs are all dataframes read in from csvs i.e.

```
acsv = read.csv("a.csv")
bcsv = read.csv("b.csv")
ccsv = read.csv("c.csv")
```

**Edit:**
I ended up using a bit of a compromise. The primary goal of this was not to simply print the frame name - that was the question, because it is a prerequisite for doing other things.

I needed to run the same functions on four identically formatted files. I then used this syntax:

```
for(i in 1:length(csvs)){
    cat(names(csvs[i]), "\n")
    print(nrow(csvs[[i]]))
    print(nrow(csvs[[i]][1]))
}
```

Then the indexing of nested lists was utilized e.g.

```
print(nrow(csvs[[i]]))
```

which shows the row count for each of the dataframes.

print(nrow(csvs[[i]][1]))

Then provides a table for the first column of each dataframe.

I include this because it was the motivator for the question. I needed to be able to label the data for each dataframe being examined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your data look like, so here's something made up:

```
csvs <- list(acsv=data.frame(x=1), bcsv=data.frame(x=2), ccsv=data.frame(x=3))
for(i in 1:length(csvs))
    cat(names(csvs[i]), "\n")
```

Comment: It works when I use the example provided. However, using the read in csvs, it does not. It returns NULL instead.

Comment: I'm going to update this, on the assumption that you have a list of dataframes. If that's not the case, please update your question with additional detail.

Comment: I checked the type of the objects and they are lists and the classes are data.frames.

Comment: The revised code works for the examples you provided; however, for my data frames, it returns 4 blank lines. I'll need to provide more data.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it does as asked. Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand how to use nested lists here e.g. how to then print(ls(csvs[i][1]) But that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `list` you have constructed doesn't "remember" the expressions it was constructed of anymore. But you can use a custom constructor:

```
named.list <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    exprs <- lapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
    names(l) <- exprs
    l
}
```

And so:

```
> named.list(1+2,sin(5),sqrt(3))
$`1 + 2`
[1] 3

$`sin(5)`
[1] -0.9589243

$`sqrt(3)`
[1] 1.732051
```

Use this list as parameter to `names`, as Thomas [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864231/946850):

```
> names(mylist(1+2,sin(5),sqrt(3)))
[1] "1 + 2"   "sin(5)"  "sqrt(3)"
```

To understand what's happening here, let's analyze the following:

```
> as.list(substitute(list(1+2,sqrt(5))))
[[1]]
list

[[2]]
1 + 2

[[3]]
sqrt(5)
```

The `[-1]` indexing leaves out the first element, and all remaining elements are passed to `deparse`, which works because of...

```
> lapply(as.list(substitute(list(1+2,sqrt(5))))[-1], class)
[[1]]
[1] "call"

[[2]]
[1] "call"
```

Note that you cannot "refactor" the call `list(...)` inside `substitute()` to use simply `l`. Do you see why?

I am also wondering if such a function is already available in one of the countless R packages around. I have found [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265516.html) by William Dunlap effectively suggesting the same approach.

Comment: `llist` in `Hmisc` is what you're looking for

Comment: @eddi: Thanks. The result of `llist(1+2,sin(5),sqrt(3))` looks slightly different to that of my function, and I fail to understand why.

Comment: This printed all the data in the data frames listed.

Comment: @krlmlr the result of `llist` is a list of labelled elements (where `label` is also introduced in `Hmisc`) - so it stores a little more stuff than your function

Comment: @Donnied: What call did print all the data?

Comment: When I tried to put the dataframes in a list with the function e.g. named.list(df1, df2, df3)

Comment: @Donnied: Try to use `named.list` instead of `list` in Thomas's code. What do you want to achieve anyway? (You can edit your question.)